# Draw tikz plot with dashed and curved lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like some help to get this plot:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x y
-4, 5.1
-3.95, 5
-3.95, 4.9
-3.95, 1
-3, 0.5
-3, -1.5
-2, -0.75
0.25, -0.75
1, -1
1.2, -0.75
1.5, -1
3, -0.25
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
x y
-4, 0.5
-3.95, 3
-2, 4
-1.5, 0.5
-0.5, 3.2
-0.7, -0.25
0.2, 0.1
0.3, -0.75
0.3, -1.85
0.45, 1
1.2, -0.75
1.35, -1.8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1},
%    ->=latex,
    xmin=-5.5,
    xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-6.5,
    ymax=6.5,
    height=4cm,
    width=5cm,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
 %   xlabel style={below right},
 %   ylabel style={above left}
    ]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot [only marks,mark=x,red,mark options={scale=1}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot [only marks,mark=x,red,mark options={scale=1}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data2.csv};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please place the result of your code and state the problems you're having.

Comment: Your image shows 2 plots and a bunch of other stuff, but your code only seems to include one and you only seem to have one lot of data. Maybe the idea is obvious to you .... Right now, it looks like the problem is just that you haven't finished.

Comment: @cfr, I have added the second data and graph.  Thanks.

Comment: @CroCo, I wanted some help to get the plot to look like the image that I have attached.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have formulas for the various lines you want to draw?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, My apologies, I do not have formulas for the various lines...:-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approximation using some plots, some fine tuning might be desirable. I haven't added the arrow between the axes and some other stuff.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x y
-4, 5.1
-3.95, 5
-3.95, 4.9
-3.95, 1
-3, 0.5
-3, -1.5
-2, -0.75
0.25, -0.75
1, -1
1.2, -0.75
1.5, -1
3, -0.25
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
x y
-4, 0.5
-3.95, 3
-2, 4
-1.5, 0.5
-0.5, 3.2
-0.7, -0.25
0.2, 0.1
0.3, -0.75
0.3, -1.85
0.45, 1
1.2, -0.75
1.35, -1.8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1},
    xticklabels={},yticklabels={},
%    ->=latex,
    xmin=-5.5,
    xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-6.5,
    ymax=6.5,
    height=4cm,
    width=5cm,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
 %   xlabel style={below right},
 %   ylabel style={above left}
    axis lines=center,axis equal,clip=false %%%% <---- Added
    ]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot [only marks,mark=x,red,mark options={scale=1}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,4}{
\addplot [xshift=#1*0.1cm,yshift=0.5cm-0.1*#1cm,red,thin,dotted,domain=-9+#1:0+#1,rotate around={10+20*#1:(axis cs:-3.5+#1,0)}] {((x+5-2*#1)/4)^2};
}

\nextgroupplot
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2,-1,...,2}{
\addplot [thin,dotted,red,domain=-5-#1:5-#1] {x + 3*#1};
}
\addplot [-Stealth,thick,black,domain=-4:4] {-x};
\addplot [only marks,mark=x,red,mark options={scale=1}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data2.csv};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the preamble I have added the `backgrounds` tikz library. Change de groupplots options to increase the `horizontal sep` (distance between the graphs). Add option to get rid of `xlabel` and `xticks` (respectively for `ylabel` and `yticks`). And see annotation after groupplot environnement. 
Of course it is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x y
-4, 5.1
-3.95, 5
-3.95, 4.9
-3.95, 1
-3, 0.5
-3, -1.5
-2, -0.75
0.25, -0.75
1, -1
1.2, -0.75
1.5, -1
3, -0.25
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
x y
-4, 0.5
-3.95, 3
-2, 4
-1.5, 0.5
-0.5, 3.2
-0.7, -0.25
0.2, 0.1
0.3, -0.75
0.3, -1.85
0.45, 1
1.2, -0.75
1.35, -1.8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,horizontal sep=2cm},
    %->=latex,
    xmin=-5.5, xmax=5.5, ymin=-6.5, ymax=6.5,
    height=4cm, width=5cm,
    xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
    xtick =\empty, ytick =\empty,
 %   xlabel style={below right},
 %   ylabel style={above left},
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = middle,
    axis equal image,
    ]
\nextgroupplot[title=\emph{kernel PCA}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=x,red,mark options={scale=1}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot [only marks,mark=x,red,mark options={scale=1}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data2.csv};
\draw[>=stealth,->] (-4,4) -- (4,-4) node[right]{F}; % F arrow
\draw[dotted] (-4-1  ,-4+4) -- (4-1  ,4+4); 
\draw[dotted] (-4-0.5,-4+2) -- (4-0.5,4+2);
\draw[dotted] (-4-0  ,-4+0) -- (4-0  ,4+0);
\draw[dotted] (-4+0.5,-4-2) -- (4+0.5,4-2);
\draw[dotted] (-4+1  ,-4-4) -- (4+1  ,4-4);
\end{groupplot}
\draw[] (3,0.25) node[]{$k(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=(\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{y})^d$};
\draw[very thick,dashed,>=stealth,->] (2,2) node[left,above]{$\textbf{R}^2$} -- (4,2) node[midway,below]{$\Phi$};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \filldraw [line width=4mm,join=round,black!10] (0,0) rectangle (6,3);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]